# I have an error 401 with getServerSideProps with Jenkins CD

Tags: nginx, jenkins, next.js

I would like to have CI/CD for my website (fullstack with NextJS, apollo-graphql, prisma) so I installed jenkins on my server. I installed nginx and pm2 to start/restart my website.

When I start the server with root user, everything works fine, I have no issue getting the data on frontend.

After that I decided to create a jenkins user on the server that will run the Jenkins node and execute the jobs.

I configured the job to get the repo from github, install, build and start the website with pm2 and it works when there is no data fetched on the server side.

When I go to the page that get the data on server side, I see a error 500 on front and in the logs on the server I see this :

```
2|mywebsite  | ApolloError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
2|mywebsite  |     at new ApolloError (/home/jenkins/workspace/mywebsite/node_modules/@apollo/client/errors/errors.cjs:34:28)
2|mywebsite  |     at /home/jenkins/workspace/mywebsite/node_modules/@apollo/client/core/core.cjs:1658:19
2|mywebsite  |     at both (/home/jenkins/workspace/mywebsite/node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs:985:53)
2|mywebsite  |     at /home/jenkins/workspace/mywebsite/node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs:978:72
2|mywebsite  |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
2|mywebsite  |     at Object.then (/home/jenkins/workspace/mywebsite/node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs:978:24)
2|mywebsite  |     at Object.error (/home/jenkins/workspace/mywebsite/node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs:986:49)
2|mywebsite  |     at notifySubscription (/home/jenkins/workspace/mywebsite/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:140:18)
2|mywebsite  |     at onNotify (/home/jenkins/workspace/mywebsite/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:179:3)
2|mywebsite  |     at SubscriptionObserver.error (/home/jenkins/workspace/mywebsite/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:240:7) {
2|mywebsite  |   graphQLErrors: [],
2|mywebsite  |   clientErrors: [],
2|mywebsite  |   networkError: SyntaxError [ServerParseError]: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
2|mywebsite  |       at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
2|mywebsite  |       at /home/jenkins/workspace/mywebsite/node_modules/@apollo/client/link/http/http.cjs:18:25
2|mywebsite  |       at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
2|mywebsite  |       at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
2|mywebsite  |     response: Response {
2|mywebsite  |       size: 0,
2|mywebsite  |       timeout: 0,
2|mywebsite  |       [Symbol(Body internals)]: [Object],
2|mywebsite  |       [Symbol(Response internals)]: [Object]
2|mywebsite  |     },
2|mywebsite  |     statusCode: 401,
2|mywebsite  |     bodyText: '<html>\n' +
2|mywebsite  |       '<head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>\n' +
2|mywebsite  |       '<body>\n' +
2|mywebsite  |       '<center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>\n' +
2|mywebsite  |       '<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0</center>\n' +
2|mywebsite  |       '</body>\n' +
2|mywebsite  |       '</html>\n'
2|mywebsite  |   },
2|mywebsite  |   extraInfo: undefined
2|mywebsite  | }
```

Do I have any configuration to do with Nginx ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

That was not due to Nginx configuration, it was due to the apollo client configuration:

```
const apolloClient = () => {
  return new ApolloClient({
    uri: `${process.env.BASE_URL ?? ''}/api/graphql`,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  })
}
```

The environement variable was the website url, but when I changed it to htt://localhost:3000 (the server is running on port 3000,  if you have the same issue change the port), it worked fine.